# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin while doing jquery ajax Get

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery ajax to download xml from here:
http://www.maciejko-sklep.pl/components/com_esklep/integracja.php?type=cenuj&pass=JH64HU7

or either html:
link: http://www.maciejko-sklep.pl/components/com_esklep/integracja.php?type=html&pass=4FMIHGfd

and I get this error Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I'm trying to figure this out, anyone knows how to fix this and somehow download content from either of those links. P.s. when i paste the link in url it works fine, but i cannot send ajax requests. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solved this issue
http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-xml-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain ajax requests are restricted by the browser, unless the server explicitly has [cors enabled](http://enable-cors.org/).

Comment: how do I download the xml then? and parse in the browser? any idea of any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your php file:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

It solved my issue with access-control-allow-origin

Comment: i'm not using php, just pure javascript + jquery in my client side, what should I exactly do in this case?

Comment: You can't add it to the integracja.php page?

Comment: ok gotta contact my friend, it is his site but he only uses it through admin interface, i hope there is option to play around with the source code, it is some e-shop component

Comment: I think it'll be your best bet. If not take a look here for other ways you might be able to achieve this: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: got it to work thanks to this post http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-xml-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/          and your suggestion :)